# Can I scope style to a dynamic Svelte component?

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte, vite, sveltekit, postcss

I'm having trouble applying scoped styles to dynamic svelte components. I'm using mdsvex to render markdown content in a +page.svelte template. Some of the content meta (post.title, post.date) is delivered directly to the +page.svelte template, but the content is delivered through a dynamic component:

```
// blog/[slug]/+page.svelte

<hgroup>
    <h1>{data.meta.title}<h1>
</hgroup>
<svelte:component this={data.content} />
```

I found out how to scope Tailwind classes to the content of the template, like this:

```
// blog/[slug]/+page.svelte

<style lang=postcss>
    h1 {
        @apply text-3xl font-bold text-primary-500
    }
</style>
```

How do I get those scoped classes to apply to the content of the dynamic Svelte component as well? Is it possible?

For now, the scoped styles only apply to the rendered content meta directly inside +page.svelte. (Which is irrelevant since I could simply inline the classes on those elements, which is something I cannot do on the markdown content, which is why scoped style on the dynamic component containing the body of the markdown content would be useful.)

I hope this makes sense, please point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a wrapper, use that to scope and then [`:global`](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#style) to target elements in the dynamically rendered content:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <svelte:component ... />
</div>
<style lang=postcss>
    .wrapper { display: contents; } /* if necessary for layout */
    .wrapper :global(.some-selector) {
        @apply font-bold
    }
</style>
```